# how to do dividing between matrices?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Today I encountered a piece of MATLAB code, which I can't understand well. It is

```
(Dpatch - min(Dpatch(:))) / (max(Dpatch(:)) - min(Dpatch(:)))
```

`Dpatch` is a n*n matrix here.

So what we will get after dividing a n*n matrix by a 1*n matrix ?

Hoping for your help, thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try executing the statement and finding out, for yourself, what it does ?

Comment: Hint: see the size of `min(Dpatch(:))`

Comment: That code normalizes/scales the individual elements of the matrix to range 0..1. (0 for minimum, 1 for maximum). Matrix / vector is not defined. OTOH, if n=1, the division returns 0/0 or NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that, what *LuisMendo* mentiones in his comment is the clue to your understanding problem, but deserves more explanation since it's a Matlab-typical, elegant but obfuscated way of doing things.

Normaly `min` operates in one dimension only. E.g. `min(Dpatch)` would return the minimum of each column. Or `min(Dpatch, [], 2)` the minimum of each row. Now `Dpatch(:)` flattens the matrix to a one dimensional array such that `min(Dpatch(:))` will return the minimum over all the values in the matrix which is just a number. The same holds of course for `max`.

Although there seems to be a n*n by 1*n division here, there really is only a n*n by 1 elementwise divsion. (By the way n*n divided by 1*n **is** defined as inversion similar to `A*pinv(B)`, see [`help slash`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/mrdivide.html)).

Hence, as pointed out by *AkiSuihkonen*, your line of code just projects the matrix `Dpatch` from its range onto the `[0, 1]` range.

Comment: The key is Dpatch(:) makes a one dimensional array, the useage of matlab I am not familiar with. Thank you very much for your detailed and clear explanation !

Answer (score 0):

You can translate this as (Matrix - Number)/(Number - Number), which is (Matrix - Number) /Number which is Matrix (with the same size as the original one :)